# How to use the MySQL where clause to query whether a user's all tags are in the parameter list

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis, relational-division

I use MySql 8.0 to query a user whose tags are all in parameter list，but I don't know how to write the `WHERE` clause to query the answer. the following is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_tag`
(
    `user_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `tag_id`  BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `tag_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Thanks in advance!

for example, if I have some rows:

| user_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

suppose my parameter list is `[2, 3, 4]`, if I do the query `Long findUserByTagList(List<Long> tagIdList)`, the expect answer is `1` (Because the user id contains all tags in the parameter list, but user id 2 don't have all tags in the parameter list).

I tried to use the following SQL to do the query（Spring Boot + MyBatis）:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `user_id`
FROM `user_tag`
WHERE `tag_id` IN
<foreach collection="tagIdList" index="index" item="item" separator="," open="(" close=")">
    #{item}
</foreach>
```

But the results were not the same as expected. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want users that have parameters `2`, `3` and `4`, you can use `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` in SQL:

```
select user_id
from user_tag
where tag_id in (2, 3, 4)
group by user_id
having count(*) = 3
```

This filters on users that have at least one of the three tags (in the `WHERE` clause), then groups by user, and ensures that each user has three matches.

If you have duplicate `(user_id, tag_id)`, then you would need `distinct`:

```
select user_id
from user_tag
where tag_id in (2, 3, 4)
group by user_id
having count(distinct tag_id) = 3
```

A slightly different approach does all the filtering in the `HAVING` claiuse (but that might be less efficient):

```
select user_id
from user_tag
group by user_id
having max(tag_id = 2) = 1 and max(tag_id = 3) = 1 and max(tag_id = 4) = 1
```